# Multithreading in Unity on Android

Tags: c#, android, multithreading, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Some "long work" needs to be performed during game process. Obviously game freezes on 1-2 seconds when this work is being performed. So i put algorithm of "long work" to second thread and, as was expected, freezing has disappeared... but only on PC. Game still freezed on android device.

Please, tell me what I could have missed. Perhaps there are some compilation options that forbid multithreading or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threads work as they must. To find the real problem you should use profiler. They will show you when, where and why the program freezes.